# Как узнать, какому файлу принадлежит сектор диска?

Tags: linux, ntfs, поиск-программ, ddrescue

При помощи `ddrescue` создан образ диска. К нему есть карта, что не удалось скопировать. Начинается вот так:

```
# Rescue Logfile. Created by GNU ddrescue version 1.17
# Command line: ddrescue -v -d --max-retries=1 --cluster-size=3 /dev/sdb2 d.img d.log
# current_pos  current_status
0xA7459CBA00     +
#      pos        size  status
0x00000000  0x52C15CAC00  +
0x52C15CAC00  0x00000400  -
0x52C15CB000  0x00011600  +
```

Насколько я понимаю, это означает, что `0x400` байт начиная с `0x52C15CAC00` не удалось прочитать. Как понять, какие именно файлы повреждены? Файловая система NTFS.

Comment: http://radagast.ca/linux/how-to-find-the-ntfs-filename-associated-with-a-bad-block-using-linux.html

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, в принципе да (почему не ответом-то?), но для разных записей не очень подходит, т. к. `ntfscluster` только непрерывную цепочку кластеров понимает, набор вроде нельзя перечислить? Но у меня их немного, так что сгодится.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, а ещё, можно пояснить перенаправление stderr?

Comment: *набор вроде нельзя перечислить?* это же не *ms/windows*. здесь подобное сделать несложно: `for i in 0-100 101-200 201-300; do sudo ntfscluster -s $i раздел; done`. *можно пояснить перенаправление stderr?* — да, спрашивайте.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, 1. Но ведь для каждой итерации будет заново сканироваться вся файловая система, т. е. при `n` диапазонах вычисление займёт в `n` раз больше времени, чем необходимо - как-то нерационально? 2. Про stderr - что он туда выводит, зачем нужно это перенаправление?

Comment: 1. не думаю, что «вся фс» — запрашиваются же конкретные кластеры/секторы. но если это действительно проблема, то чуть дополнить функц-сть программы, думаю, несложно. и другим людям польза будет. 2. а, это вы про *step 3* по ссылке? ну, автор, видимо, неспроста использует опцию `-f` — у него там, наверно, ошибки какие-то выводятся. вот он их и перенаправляет в `/dev/null`.

Comment: 1. А разве можно определить принадлежность кластера файлу, не перебирая тупо файлы до тех пор, пока на найдётся соответствие? Для меня сейчас не проблема, т. к. диапазонов мало, но в целом - как-то это не очень красиво. 2. Дело в том, что у меня они тоже выводятся, причём на нормальном томе (по крайней мере, я его считаю нормальным; пожалуй, когда буду в винде, проверю через chkdsk) - вот и подумал, что неспроста там это перенаправление.

Comment: 1. понятия не имею. я вообще никогда не сталкивался с *ntfs*. кстати, документацию (вероятно, результаты реверс-инжиниринга) можно взять из [этого пакета](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/ntfsdoc). 2. да просто для того, чтобы не засорять инструкцию ненужной информацией.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, 1. Думаю, это для любой фс одинаково? Для файла хранится описание, где он лежит, а не для кластера описание, что в нём. Пользователь же кластерами не интересуется обычно.

Comment: я понятия не имею, как организована информация в *ntfs*, и что в приложении к этой фс означает термин *cluster*. ни в одной из фс, которыми я пользуюсь, насколько мне известно, никаких *cluster*-ов нет.

Answer (score 3):

как пишут [здесь](http://radagast.ca/linux/how-to-find-the-ntfs-filename-associated-with-a-bad-block-using-linux.html), нужно разделить номер блока на размер кластера, используемого данной файловой системой, и перевести результат в десятичную систему счисления.

размер кластера:

```
$ sudo ntfsinfo -m раздел | grep -i 'cluster size'
        Cluster Size: 4096
```

в шестнадцатиричной это будет:

```
$ echo 'obase=16;4096' | bc
1000
```

делим номер из вопроса (0x52C15CAC00) на 1000 и получаем результат в десятичной системе счисления:

```
$ echo 'ibase=16;52C15CAC00/1000' | bc
86775242
```

узнаём, что за файл(ы) располагаются в этом кластере (пример вывода команды взят из вышеупомянутой инструкции):

```
$ sudo ntfscluster -c 86775242 раздел
Searching for cluster 9369
Inode 89381 /Windows/System32/atidxx64.dll/$DATA
```

Comment: Я тут что-то нагородил на основе этой схемы - можешь посмотреть и сказать, как улучшить?

Comment: У меня `ntfscluster` тоже хочет `-f`, но я не монтировал диск.

Answer (score 3):

## В линуксе можно использовать следующее решение:

```
filename=d.img
logname=d.log
clsz=$(sudo ntfsinfo -m -f $filename 2>/dev/null | grep 'Cluster Size' | \
sed -r "s/.*:/obase=16;/" | bc)
for r in $(cat $logname | grep '-' | grep -v 'ddrescue' | \
sed -r "s/0x(\w+)\s+0x(\w+)\s+.*/\1\/$clsz; (\1+\2)\/$clsz/;1s/^/ibase=16\n" | \
bc | tr '\n' '-' | sed -r 's/(\w+-\w+)-/\1\n/g' | uniq | tr '\n' ' ' | \
sed -r 's/-(\w+) \1\b//g' | sed -r 's/ /\n/g' | \
sed -r 's/(\w+)-(\w+)/\1;\2;\2+1;/' | bc | tr '\n' '-' | \
sed -r 's/(\w+-\w+-\w+)-/\1 /g' | sed -r 's/-\w+-(\w+) \1//g' | \
sed -r 's/(-\w+)-\w+/\1/g'); \
do sudo ntfscluster -f -c $r $filename 2>/dev/null; done
```

Замечу, что надо предварительно выполнить любую команду `sudo`, чтобы последняя команда не съелась в качестве пароля. Тогда на остальные команды пароль запрашиваться не будет и всё будет работать.

***Существенный минус этого решения - то, что для каждого диапазона кластеров снова сканируется файловая система, т. е. работает очень медленно.***

---

Теперь поясню, что же здесь происходит.

## Сначала определим размер кластера

Информацию о диске можно получить при помощи `ntfsinfo`.
Опция `-f` нужна чтобы образ не ставился на проверку с просьбой перезагрузиться дважды.
Перенаправление ошибок в `/dev/null` чтобы избавиться от `WARNING: Dirty volume mount was forced by the 'force' mount option.`

```
sudo ntfsinfo -m -f d.img 2>/dev/null
```

Выберем отсюда строку с информацией о размере кластера:

```
... | grep 'Cluster Size'
```

Достанем из неё число и переведём в 16ричную систему счисления:

```
... | sed -r "s/.*:/obase=16;/" | bc
```

Сохраним в переменную:

```
clsz=$(...)
```

#### Команда целиком:

```
clsz=$(sudo ntfsinfo -m -f d.img 2>/dev/null | grep 'Cluster Size' | \
sed -r "s/.*:/obase=16;/" | bc)
```

Вероятно, получится значение 1000.

## Теперь определим диапазоны кластеров

Выберем из карты все плохие куски (содержат `-` и не являются строкой с самой командой):

```
cat d.log | grep '-' | grep -v 'ddrescue'
```

Получится нечто такое:

```
0x52C15CAC00  0x00000400  -
0x52C15DC600  0x00000200  -
0xA74593D600  0x00000200  -
0xA74593DA00  0x00000600  -
0xA74593E600  0x00000200  -
0xA745945000  0x00000400  -
0xA745945600  0x00000200  -
0xA745945C00  0x00000400  -
0xA745947600  0x00000200  -
0xA7459C3200  0x00000C00  -
0xA7459CB000  0x00000200  -
0xA7459CB400  0x00000200  -
0xA7459CB800  0x00000400  -
```

Преобразуем в формулы для вычисления номеров кластеров в 16ричной системе счисления:

```
... | sed -r "s/0x(\w+)\s+0x(\w+)\s+.*/\1\/$clsz; (\1+\2)\/$clsz/;1s/^/ibase=16\n/"
```

```
ibase=16; 52C15CAC00/1000; (52C15CAC00+00000400)/1000; ibase=A;
ibase=16; 52C15DC600/1000; (52C15DC600+00000200)/1000; ibase=A;
ibase=16; A74593D600/1000; (A74593D600+00000200)/1000; ibase=A;
ibase=16; A74593DA00/1000; (A74593DA00+00000600)/1000; ibase=A;
ibase=16; A74593E600/1000; (A74593E600+00000200)/1000; ibase=A;
ibase=16; A745945000/1000; (A745945000+00000400)/1000; ibase=A;
ibase=16; A745945600/1000; (A745945600+00000200)/1000; ibase=A;
ibase=16; A745945C00/1000; (A745945C00+00000400)/1000; ibase=A;
ibase=16; A745947600/1000; (A745947600+00000200)/1000; ibase=A;
ibase=16; A7459C3200/1000; (A7459C3200+00000C00)/1000; ibase=A;
ibase=16; A7459CB000/1000; (A7459CB000+00000200)/1000; ibase=A;
ibase=16; A7459CB400/1000; (A7459CB400+00000200)/1000; ibase=A;
ibase=16; A7459CB800/1000; (A7459CB800+00000400)/1000; ibase=A;
```

И вычислим

```
... | bc
```

```
86775242
86775243
86775260
86775260
175397181
175397181
175397181
175397182
175397182
175397182
175397189
175397189
175397189
175397189
175397189
175397190
175397191
175397191
175397315
175397315
175397323
175397323
175397323
175397323
175397323
175397323
```

К сожалению, числа получились на разных строках - объединяем их через дефис, затем каждый второй дефис заменяем переводом строки, затем уберём дубликаты строк:

```
... | tr '\n' '-' | sed -r 's/(\w+-\w+)-/\1\n/g' | uniq
```

```
86775242-86775243
86775260-86775260
175397181-175397181
175397181-175397182
175397182-175397182
175397189-175397189
175397189-175397190
175397191-175397191
175397315-175397315
175397323-175397323
```

Объединим последовательные цепочки, если конечный кластер первой совпадает с начальным следующей. Для этого объединим строки через пробел и поудаляем `-число такое-же-число\b`. У меня `sed` не съел `\d`, поэтому я использовал `\w`. После замены вернём на место переводы строк.

```
... | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -r 's/-(\w+) \1\b//g' | sed -r 's/ /\n/g'
```

```
86775242-86775243
86775260-86775260
175397181-175397182
175397189-175397190
175397191-175397191
175397315-175397315
175397323-175397323
```

Приготовимся посчитать номер следующего за концом кластера:

```
... | sed -r 's/(\w+)-(\w+)/\1;\2;\2+1;/'
```

```
86775242;86775243;86775243+1;
86775260;86775260;86775260+1;
175397181;175397182;175397182+1;
175397189;175397190;175397190+1;
175397191;175397191;175397191+1;
175397315;175397315;175397315+1;
175397323;175397323;175397323+1;
```

И вычислим это:

```
... | bc
```

```
86775242
86775243
86775244
86775260
86775260
86775261
175397181
175397182
175397183
175397189
175397190
175397191
175397191
175397191
175397192
175397315
175397315
175397316
175397323
175397323
175397324
```

По аналогии с прошлым разом, объединяем строки через дефис, а каждый третий дефоис заменяем пробелом:

```
... | tr '\n' '-' | sed -r 's/(\w+-\w+-\w+)-/\1 /g'
```

Объединяем цепочки, где начальный кластер следующий совпадает со следующим за конечным кластером предыдущей:

```
... | sed -r 's/-\w+-(\w+) \1//g'
```

```
86775242-86775243-86775244 86775260-86775260-86775261 175397181-175397182-175397183 175397189-175397191-175397192 175397315-175397315-175397316 175397323-175397323-175397324
```

Убираем лишнюю информацию о следующем кластере:

```
... | sed -r 's/(-\w+)-\w+/\1/g'
```

```
86775242-86775243 86775260-86775260 175397181-175397182 175397189-175397191 175397315-175397315 175397323-175397323
```

#### Команда целиком:

```
cat d.log | grep '-' | grep -v 'ddrescue' | \
sed -r "s/0x(\w+)\s+0x(\w+)\s+.*/\1\/$clsz; (\1+\2)\/$clsz/;1s/^ibase=16\n/" | \
bc | tr '\n' '-' | sed -r 's/(\w+-\w+)-/\1\n/g' | uniq | tr '\n' ' ' | \
sed -r 's/-(\w+) \1\b//g' | sed -r 's/ /\n/g' | \
sed -r 's/(\w+)-(\w+)/\1;\2;\2+1;/' | bc | tr '\n' '-' | \
sed -r 's/(\w+-\w+-\w+)-/\1 /g' | sed -r 's/-\w+-(\w+) \1//g' | \
sed -r 's/(-\w+)-\w+/\1/g'
```

## Используем список для поиска файлов:

Оборачиваем получившуюся выше конструкцию в качестве набора для цикла for:

```
for r in $(...); do echo $r; done
```

Ну и наконец меняем `echo $r` на нечто полезное:

```
sudo ntfscluster -f -c $r d.img 2>/dev/null
```

В итоге получается интересующий нас список файлов вместе с указанием кластеров.

Comment: 1. длинные команды лучше разбивать так, чтобы на экран влезали. 2. что бросилось в глаза: при формировании программы для bc нет необходимости постоянно переопределять ibase. достаточно один раз в начале первой строки: `sed -r "s/0x(\w+)\s+0x(\w+)\s+.*/\1\/$clsz; (\1+\2)\/$clsz/;1s/^/ibase=16\n/"`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, про подстановку только в начало не знал, вот и гонял туда-сюда, чтоб в каждой строке работало. У меня вообще этот код вызывает ощущение, что её можно в несколько раз сократить, если использовать нормальные (или нормальнее) команды?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, из-за цикла этот код работает 135 секунд вместо 28. Первое сканирование 28 секунд, второе 24, остальные около 21. Если битых областей будет больше - это станет критичной проблемой. Надо что-то, что съест сразу комплект кластеров...

Comment: настало время пропатчить ntfscluster?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, а менее радикальное?)))

Comment: использовать ssd, докупить оперативной памяти и более крутой процессор с материнской платой.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, оперативная память тут вроде не в тему - вся обработка ведь потоковая. Как и процессор. Тут скорость чтения ограничителем выступает.

Comment: хорошо, на памяти можете сэкономить.

Comment: *а менее радикальное?* — кстати, в файле `ntfsprogs/ntfscluster.c` всего-то 567 строк. а файл, где реализована ключевая функция cluster_find, `ntfsprogs/cluster.c`, вообще содержит всего 132 строки. для опытного «сишника» чуть расширить функциональность — по-моему, как два пальца о винчестер. предлагаю синтаксис: `-c 1-2,10-20,5-6...`