# Восстановление windows 7 с повреждённого диска

Tags: linux, windows, gparted, gpt

Здравствуйте.

```
Имеется sda=247гб и sdb=500гб  
sda1=100mb зарезервированно системой 
sda2=47gb ОС Windows - ntfs диск С 
sda3=200gb ntfs диск D 
sdb1=500gb ntfs backup

sudo dd if=/sda1 of=/backup/sda1.img
sudo dd if=/sda2 of=/backup/sda2.img
sudo dd if=/sda3 of=/backup/sda3.img
```

В sda на 1656 мегабайте ошибка. Решил подвинуть sda2 на 2Гб. Ни акронис, ни нортон, ни gparted не смогли увидеть разделы sda, вероятно потому как там GPT. В ubuntu 16.04 диски замечательно смонтировались и данные были доступны для копирования. На всякий случай скопировал ещё и пофайлово, был повреждён файл лога и какой то системный файл которые я пропустил. 
Чтобы gparted увидел диски пришлось использовать использовать fixparts

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sda > /backup/parts.txt
sudo su
fixparts
/dev/sda
p - показал две партиции похожего размера
w
```

Gparted увидел разделы. Уменьшить sda3 не удалось, он был удалён. sda2 был передвинут на 2Гб успешно (не считая пары ошибок которые я проигнорировал). Gparted показал что на sda2 что то есть. Создал sda3 на оставшемся месте перенёс на него изначальные данные.
Перезагружаю. Дальше загрузочника ничего не идёт. Пытаюсь сделать восстановление используя флешку с windows 7 (какая там версия ОС мне точно не известно) восстанавливать отказался. Устанавливать на такие разделы тоже не захотел. Всё удалил на sda, переразметил, установка пошла. На этом пока остановился.

Как мне в данном случае поступить наиболее грамотно, есть предложения? Проблема в первую очередь с настроенным ПО, которое стояло на sda.

Comment: Может, пригодится: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/502023/178988

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поступил следующим образом:

1. Исправил ошибку чтения программой victoria 3.5 [используя режим «Classic REMAP»](http://www.ihdd.ru/victoria-doc-ru)
2. Сделал новую разметку диска
3. Скопировал имеющиеся данные на заменённые разделы
4. Сделал восстановление запуска
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. [Восстановил целостность системных файлов](http://remontcompa.ru/583-kak-proizvesti-vosstanovlenie-celostnosti-sistemnyh-faylov-esli-windows-8-ne-zagruzhaetsya.html) командой:

   sfc /scannow /offbootdir=С:\ /offwindir=С:\Windows
6. Заменил файлы реестра на предыдущие C:\Windows\System32\Config файлы SAM, SECURITY, SOFTWARE, DEFAULT, SYSTEM на те же из C:\Windows\System32\Config\RegBack

использовал материал [отсюда](http://remontcompa.ru/index.php?newsid=151).