# Объединить строки с поиском по шаблону

Tags: строки, bash, perl, sed, awk

Задача найти по регулярному выражению(шаблон) строку и объединить ту строку со следующей и/или предыдущей. Любой намек на вариант в sed или awk или perl.

Comment: Приемы подбные этому `perl -pe 's/какой-то текст\n//g'`, заменяет весь шаблон с переводом строки на пустоту, это может и решает часть задачи, но все же хочется  объеденить строки при нахождении "регулярки". 

И хочется решение именно уровня скрипта в bash, а не С.

Answer (score 0):

file:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Вывести строку 3 и две строки после нее в одной строке

```
cat file | grep 3 -A2 | xargs
```

A = After. Результат: `3 4 5`

Вывести строку 3 и две строку до нее в одной строке

```
cat file | grep 3 -B2 | xargs
```

B = Before. Результат: `1 2 3`

Если же прямо вот awk нужен, то можно так (вывести строку 3 и одну после нее):

```
awk '$1=="3" {print n,$1} {n=$1}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Для замены переводов строк можно использовать `tr`. Потом придётся строки как-то поделить заново, но для некоторых задач подходит: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/502102/178988.

Если в каждой строке находится слово:

```
cat file | tr '\n' '-' | sed -r 's/(\w+-\w+)-/\1\n/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Приемы подбные этому `perl -pe 's/какой-то текст\n//g'`, заменяет весь шаблон с переводом строки на пустоту, это может и решает часть задачи, но все же хочется объеденить строки при нахождении "регулярки".

Ну, вероятно, тогда так:

```
perl -pe 's/(какой-то текст)\n/$1/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Как бы я решил данную задачу:

1) меняем символ перевода строки `\n` на любой символ, который не встретится в файле, буду использовать `~`

```
tr '\n' '~'
```

далее `sed` ищу совпадение текста по группа с использованием регулярного выражения, после возвращаю переносы строки на место:

-для объединения со следующей строкой

```
sed -r 's/(inet [0-9.]+[^~]+)(~)/\1 /g;s/~/\n/g'
```

-для объединения с предыдущей строкой

```
sed -r 's/(~)[^~]+(inet [0-9.]+[^~]+)/\2/g;s/~/\n/g'
```

На примере `ifconfig`

```
ifconfig | tr '\n' '~' | sed -r 's/(inet [0-9.]+[^~]+)(~)/\1 /g;s/~/\n/g'
ifconfig | tr '\n' '~' | sed -r 's/(~)[^~]+(inet [0-9.]+[^~]+)/\2/g;s/~/\n/g'
```

решение не совсем правильное, но работает. Выводом будет весь текст из файла/вывода и объединение строк. Опасностью в данном случае будет появление символа на который меняем символ перевода строки, поэтому если и использовать этот метод, то нужно понимать что за данные будут обрабатываться.