# Поиск блока кода в regexxer

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, sed

Как в regexxer можно искать фрагменты кода если этот фрагмент занимает например 3 линейки. В качестве примера надо найти этот участок кода :

```
<li>
    <a href="javascript:DialerPopForm();" id="tabs-conteiner-delete">Стать дилером</a>
</li>
```

Пробывал так искать:

```
<li>\s+<a\s+href\="\.\./where\-to\-buy\.html"\s+id\="tabs\-conteiner\-delete">SKLEPY</a>\s+</li>
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: [Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/502102/178988) много на эту тему.

Comment: Используйте XPath.

Comment: Переношу комментарий **0andriy**: XPath для случая OP: `'//li[a[@id="tabs-conteiner-delete"]]`. Дальше, например, удаление с помощью `xmlstarlet ed --delete '//li[a[@id="tabs-conteiner-delete"]]' input.html > output.html`. Этой утилите требуется корректный DOM. Поломанные HTML надо вначале починить. Очевидно можно найти утилиты, которые умеют обрабатывать HTML. Простой же поиск — `xmllint --html --xpath '//li[a[@id="tabs-conteiner-delete"]]' input.html`

Comment: @PotroNik Добрый день ещё раз. Почему то этот код не работает хотя по твоим правилам расстовлял все 
`find -name '*.html' -exec sh -c "perl -pi -e 's/\n/~~~/g' {} ; sed -r -i 's|[~]{0,3}[ \t]{0,}<li>[\r\~]{3,4}[ \t]{0,}<a href=\"\.\.\/where\-to\-buy\.html\"  id=\"tabs\-conteiner\-delete\">SKLEPY</a>[\r~]{3,4}[ \t]{0,}</li>||g;s|~~~|\n|g' {}" \;`

Comment: @urbanbrains `href=\"\.\.\/where\-to\-buy\.html\"`  вот эта часть как в файле выглядит?

Comment: @PotroNik `href="../where-to-buy.html"` но есть еще и `href="../../where-to-buy.html" href="../../../where-to-buy.html"`

Comment: @urbanbrains попробуйте заменить на `href="[\./]+where-to-buy.html`

Comment: @PotroNik Спасибо все заработало. Только то что вчера делали сработало только на 1 файл вот та команда `find -name '*.html' -exec sh -c "perl -pi -e 's/\n/~~~/g' {} ; sed -r -i 's|[~]{0,3}<li>[\r\~]{3,4}[ \t]{0,}<a href=\"javascript:DialerPopForm\(\);\" id=\"tabs-conteiner-delete\">Стать дилером</a>[\r~]{3,4}</li>||g;s|~~~|\n|g' {}" \;
`